# Perform pre and post processing with sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

How can I perform post processing on my SQL3 database via python? The following code doesn't work, but what I am trying to do is first create a new database if not exists already, then insert some data, and finally execute the query and close the connection. But I what to do so separately, so as to add additional functionality later on, such as delete /  updater / etc... Any ideas?

```
class TitlesDB:
    # initiate global variables
    conn = None
    c = None
    # perform pre - processing
    def __init__(self, name):
        import os
        os.chdir('/../../')
        import sqlite3
        conn = sqlite3.connect(name)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS titles (title VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE)')
    # insert a bunch of new titles
    def InsertTitles(self, list):
        c.executemany('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO titles VALUES (?)', list)
    # perform post - processing
    def __fina__(self):
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Why did you think that a `__fina__` method would allow for post processing?

Comment: And I strongly suspect that `os.chdir('/../../') would get you nowhere. It's two dirs up from the root dir.

Comment: just think out of the box for a minute... `__fina__` is for demo purposes only (just to illustrate what I want to do), and '/../../' means simply that I do not want to reveal where I store my tiny database...

Comment: so, do you have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, wouldn't it be better to avoid having the sql connection inside the `__init__`?
You will have a problem if you want to use this class in the same instance after using `__fina__`.
You could have it in another method and call it and call the connection closing method when needed and commit after each method is executed.

Here is what I use : Create a class method that connects to the db and executes a query from an argument,commits and closes connection and you pass any query you want executed as an argument of that method.You can simply call this method anytime you want.
And the best about this is that you can create a method that passes multiple queries as arguments before closing db connection.
This is specially usefull if have to use sql connections to the same db in another class without using a set of methods each time you need to execute a sql query.

Here is a little example I used with MySQLdb module, It's pretty simple but it worked.

```
import MySQLdb

class DbQuery:
    '''Here is the class I talked about'''
    def __init__(self):
        '''You can define the main queries here but it's not necessary
           They can be global variables
           If you don't have class dependency from which you get variables
           you might not even need to define __init__'''
    def Sql_Connect(self):
        self.db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","data_db" )
        self.cursor = db.cursor()
    def Sql_Commit(self):
        self.db.commit()
        print "Info : Database updated"
        except:
           self.db.rollback()
           print "Error : Database rollback"
        self.db.close()
    def Query(self,query):
        self.Sql_Connect()
        try :
            self.cursor.execute(query)
        self.Sql_Commit()
```

The only thing important is to remember the query structure.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for your answer. Sounds a very good idea. May I ask you to publish some code?

Comment: Why not, I'm working on something right now, I'll give you a code example in a short while by editing the message, you should give it a try meanwhile ! It's a very good exercise for code structure in python !

Answer (score 0):

You could create a context manager to do the pre- and postprocessing.

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def titles_cursor():
    # perform pre - processing
    conn = sqlite3.connect(name)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS titles (title VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE)')

    yield c

    # perform post - processing
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Use it in a `with` statement:

```
with titles_cursor() as c:        
    c.executemany('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO titles VALUES (?)', list)
```